# Разработка под различные экраны/положения экрана

Tags: android, android-fragment

Много лет пишу под Android, но как-то особо не задумывался раньше об этом. Как правило проекты были строги portrait. Если же было иначе (или же для разных размеров экрана), создавались доп. слои или другие фрагменты. И в зависимости от условий уже грузились необходимые.

Но вот сейчас задумался, а правильно ли я делаю. Может кто подскажет более правильное решение. Если всё делать одним фрагментом, но в зависимости от каких-то условий грузить разные слои с разным числом элементов, то в коде фрагмента слишком много условной логики появляется. Есть более красивый метод для этого?

Comment: Так вроде разные лайоуты делаются просто для нужных экранах и раскладываются по нужным ресурсным папкам?

Comment: @Чад ну а если у вас в этих лейаутах надо разное число элементов? На больших экран больше элементов. Тогда в коде фрагмента куча if'ов будет, что не каширно.

Comment: Так сделайте метод типа 

    findViewAndAction(ViewId, Action){
        View view = findViewById(ViewId);
        if(view!=null)
            Action
    }

и иф будет только один. Или у Вас спаггети код со всем вытекающими?

Comment: @Чад если элементов в слоях разное количество более-менее подходит. А если слои оооочень сильно отличаются? Вплоть до того, что абсолютно разные компоненты будут использоваться.

Будет много кода, в котором можно запутаться. Тогда идеальный вариант грузить разные фрагменты для разных слоёв.
Но тогда дублироваться будет код по работе с теми же элементами слоя.

Comment: @Suvitruf, тогда у Вас не верная архитектура в принципе. Если сильно отличаются - делайте разные классы, если присутствует дублирование - сделайте предка, и наследуйтесь от него разными классами.

Comment: @Чад я и прошу подсказать верную архитектуру, чтобы было минимум условной логики и минимум переиспользуемого кода.

Comment: @Чад активити и так одно. Экраны - фрагменты. На планшетах выводится на страницу график с кучей сопутствующей инфы. На телефонах схематичный график с краткой инфой. Вот, к примеру.

Comment: Тогда в чём проблема? Сопутсвующую инфу в полной и краткой инфой делайте двумя разными компонентами. На планшетный лайоут кладите компонент полной инфы на телефонный - краткой инфой. И вообще не нужны никакие ифы. Вы главное данные разделите от их отображения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пост http://habrahabr.ru/post/167315/ 
тут все очень доступно и понятно.